# Categorical axiomatization of projective spaces

Tags: reference-request, projective-space, axiomatic-geometry

In their book “Foundations of Geometry” (1960), Karol Borsuk and Wanda Szmielew give a categorical axiomatization of the projective space (three dimensional), using axioms analogous to those used by Hilbert for his axiomatization of Euclidean Geometry.

Is there more literature on this specific problem (finding categorical axiomatizations of projective spaces)?